# Is it good idea to publish MVP to Google Play under different brand name to protect launched app against negative comments?

Tags: mobile, startup

I would like to develop my mobile app following lean startup principles. As MVP I want to use very simple functional native Android app with only basic functions, in fact, it is just prototype. It will be published in Google Play. Because I don't want to spend too much time with it, there might be some bugs. I am afraid of negative comments which could affect the success of the app later. So I am deciding to publish this MVP under different brand name. What do you think about this idea?

Answer (score 0):

Some companies release in Canada as an initial test run for the western market, as it is similar to the US market, but smaller (yet large enough for meaningful results to be obtained). Might be an option worth considering.

Answer (score 0):

You could also launch a Beta version. In my opinion it is good to involve customers in the development. They are forgiving if they know the product is in development, plus customers that were involved in development often keep supporting the app, which is valuable. Also mind that you would have to do the sales twice. Just end each version with test and regression tests and put the alpha version as a clean version.